# Facebook Open Graph tags for Blogger

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, blogger

I've been struggling with these for months now.

I just changed them and the Facebook Debugger thinks everything's fine except for admins and app ID whih I hope I don't have to get into.

But, when the like button is clicked, some posts show my generic favicon, some show an image for an old post, some show no image at all, and a rare few show an image from the post.

Some of them show the correct title of the blog post, some show a link instead, some show nothing.

I was hoping that a brief snippet of text from the post would show but that never happens.

This all seems to be totally random.  Here's my code for my [site](http://speechnotrecognised.blogspot.com/):

```
<!-- BEGIN Open Graph tags -->
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='description' property='og:description'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageTitle' name='keywords'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<meta content=blog' property='og:type'/>
<meta content='http://speechnotrecognised.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/our-second-first-post_28.html' property='article:author'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.url' property='og:url'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh569/speechnotrecognised/snricon4_zpsde4bdf38.jpg' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.homepageUrl' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='blog' property='og:type'/>
<meta content='http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh569/speechnotrecognised/snricon4_zpsde4bdf38.jpg' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
<meta expr:content='&quot;en_US&quot;' property='og:locale'/>
<!-- END Open Graph tags -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with your code:
- you are using the blog title to generate keywords?!
- for individual blog posts og:type should be 'article' not 'blog';
- I don't think you can use an URL for article:author;
- you don't specify either your Facebook admin ID or the app ID;
- you should use the canonical URL instead of data:blog.homepageUrl to work around blogger's country redirection.

Here is my solution: [Open Graph markup for Blogger [version 3]](http://exde601e.blogspot.ro/2012/10/open-graph-markup-for-blogger-version-3.html)

Comment: Please add the gist of your solution to your answer. If the link you posted should ever break, your answer would then be worthless.

Comment: gxg, thank you for your response.  I'm still getting random fetching of images on my posts.  And, the blog post title is sometimes linked, sometimes not.  Do I need to wait for Facebook's cache to clear?  The delinter also, tells me there's a problem with mismatched metadata re og:site_name and that I should "provide a description even if one can be inferred from other tags."